# How to add pubsub notification to GCP storage bucket using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, bucket, gsutil

I want to add a pubsub notification for GCp storage buckets. So whenever file drop in GCP storage bucket then pubsub notification will send

Answer (score 1):

Can use Gsutil command to create pubsub notification

Select project

```
gcloud config set project <Project-Name>
```

Create Notification

```
gsutil notification create -t <Pubsub topic > -f json gs://<Bucket-name>
```

More information:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes